# BMC.ARsystem.dll and Windows Server 2012 compatibility

Tags: windows-server-2012, remedy

Is BMC.ARsystem.dll version 7.1.3128.23911 supported on Windows Server 2012? Does anyone has experience with this? I was looking for a compatibility matrix or the like on their website (communities.bmc.com)

Due to urgency of the matter from my perspective, I raise it here in addition to the forums there (it's been there a while now, compared to here). Please do let me know if this is not the proper place to put these questions, and sorry in advance if this is the case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you figured this out, but we spent three days on it.... so I thought I would share it here.

We have deployed BMC.ARSystem.dll on Windows Server 2012. We are using version 7.6 and we are using it in an ASP.Net project with .NET Framework 4.5.

These were the special steps we had to take:

1. Set your appliction pool identity in IIS to run in a 32 bit
   compatible mode. (Go to advanced Settings - Enable 32-Bi
   Applications = True)
2. Make sure you have the correct C++ dlls on your machine. It requires the following files to be installed in the windows/syswow63 folder: msvcp71.dll, msvcr71.dll
3. Make sure you include all the other Remedy dll's referenced by
   BMC.ARSystem in a folder where your application will know to look
   for it. It has about 16 references. You can put it in your bin
   folder, or in our case we specify a private path in the web.config,
   like so:

> ```
> <configuration> 
>   <runtime>
>     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
>       <probing privatePath="lib"/>
> ```

I hope this helps someone else to get this working quicker.